# Drupal 6 : views Exposed Form : rename the label of a field : please how?

Tags: theming, forms, views

I need the checkboxes labels exposed in views search pages
to be different than the checkboxes labels displayed in the node/xx/edit forms.

I found the same documentation everywhere about the way to change the label of a submit button using a template.php function (works fine) :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ($vars['form']['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-XXX') {
    $vars['form']['submit']['#value'] = 'gagarine' ;
    unset($vars['form']['submit']['#printed']);
    $vars['button'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['submit']);
  }
}
```

I can't find any accurate documentation to rename a cck field label when exposed in a search page.

edit² : cleaning the thread for relative readability since I got something working

Answer (score 1):

ok I came to this :
this looks like it does the job. maybe this could be rewieved by a DOCUMENTED drupal hacker.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook) {
  // only alter the jobs search exposed filter form
  if ($vars['form']['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-MYFORMID') {

    // change the text of an exposed field label (BEF checkboxes here)
    $vars['form'][FIELDNAMEasinurl]['#options'][0] = 'a different label in search pages' ;
    $vars['form'][FIELDNAMEasinurl]['#options'][1] = 'than in edit forms' ;
    // this particular field has a common layout not the case here :
    // this will work but not with the BEF checkboxes layout I want
    //$vars['widgets'][FIELDNAMEinternal]->widget = drupal_render($vars['form']['partage']);

    // or the field was rendered by better exposed filters (here cheboxes)
    // search into better_exposed_filters.theme the function call you need (theme_select_as..)
    $vars['widgets'][FIELDNAMEinternal]->widget = theme_select_as_checkboxes_fieldset($vars['form']['partage']);

    // Change the text on the submit button
    // [...]

  }
```